# Notification not showing in android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am trying to show a notification at a given entered by user.
This is how I set alarm.

```
Intent alarmclass = new Intent(context, notifier.class);
alarmclass.putExtra("Event", data);
alarmclass.putExtra("Items_left", 4);
alarmclass.setAction(data);                                             //To distinguish between alarms for diff event
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmclass, 0);

 Log.d("time set",String.valueOf(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
 notifalm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 notifalm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),al);
```

Notifier class that is responsible for showing notification.

```
public class notifier extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
{
    Log.d("notification ", "called");
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Items Left for " + intent.getStringExtra("Event"))
                    .setContentText("Good Luck for " + intent.getStringExtra("Event") + "You forgot to take " + intent.getStringExtra("Items_left") + " items.");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, showList.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("Event_Name",intent.getStringExtra("Event"));

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(showList.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =          stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(5, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

But notification is never shown.
Please let know where my mistake is.

Comment: check your manifest

Comment: What in it exactly? @Elsunhoty

Comment: <receiver android:name=".notifier " />

Comment: okay thankyou it worked. but "intent.getStringExtra("Items_left")" this returns null instead of 4. @Elsunhoty

Comment: `4` is not a `String`.

Comment: you should try getIntExtra()

Comment: oh god!! how can i be so stupid!! Thankyou @MikeM.